# Is it possible to listen for when the chromecast plugin connects with a device for use with the Youtube JS API?

Tags: javascript, youtube, chromecast, google-cast, youtube-javascript-api

I have a webpage that uses the iframe Youtube player api.  I'd like to give the user the ability to Chromecast the currently loaded Youtube video.

I've been looking through the [Chromecast sender guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender).  I'm only seeing how to get the session and receiver objects if the user first calls the **chrome.cast.requestSession(onRequestSessionSuccess, onLaunchError)** function by clicking a button that I create on the page.

Is there a way to get the session and receiver objects if they clicked on the Youtube player/Chrome extension button to connect to a device, and not the button I provide?

Thanks!

Comment: Both ways are supported by the Google Cast SDK.

Comment: How would you go about doing this for the Youtube player?  I've tried setting the handler  **chrome.cast.addReceiverActionListener**, but it only gets thrown if I click on the button that I created or the chrome extension button, not the Youtube chromecast button.