# Chromecast sender that knows when session started from Cast Extension

Tags: chromecast

The SDK docs for [building a Chromecast Sender](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender) on Chrome mention this:

> There is also a third way of getting a Cast session. A user with the
>   Cast extension installed in their Chrome browser can mirror any Chrome
>   tab to a Cast device. If the user lands on your site, for which you
>   have implemented a Cast app, tab mirroring will automatically trigger
>   a new Cast session instead of putting the browser in mirroring mode.

And this works just fine; however, I'd like to better understand how my sender code can know when a session has been started this way. Normally, when we set up our own trigger to start a session (i.e. the cast icon), we pass as an argument the callback that will execute when the session connection is ready, If someone visits my app and launches the Cast session directly from the extension, then, how can my app be notified? Is there an event that's raised? Does it execute its own callback (and if so, how can we hook into that callback)?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939094/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-when-the-chromecast-plugin-connects-with-a-device-f) was asked here at SO a while ago, and Leon Nicholls answered indicating that it was possible, but not how to do it. Any insights woyld be very useful.

Comment: This may provide the insights you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender#Session_management

Comment: We currently have a bug in the Chrome extension which breaks this feature. It doesn't work the first time the app registers, but should work the next time. A fix is being worked on for the next release.